# How do I debug an app on the Mac that accesses the camera?

Tags: macos, qt, lldb

My Qt C++ app captures video from the camera on the Mac. It has the `NSCameraUsageDescription` value set in its plist file. But, not surprisingly, this doesn't help if I am running it using lldb, either from the commandline or from Qt Creator. It just crashes with the line:

```
2020-02-28 15:32:14.462735-0500 mqtt[47726:867880] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

So how do I do that for lldb? It is in Qt Creator's Info.plist but I guess that doesn't help if it is running via lldb.

Comment: Can you try Double-click launching your app, then attaching with lldb (or use Debug->Attach To Process in Xcode) to see if that crashes?  lldb launch doesn't perfectly emulate LaunchServices (i.e. Finder double-clicking) launches, and that can cause the app not to get some rights that it would have been granted by LaunchServices.

Comment: @JimIngham while I can do that, it doesn't help in the case where it is crashing on startup

Comment: I thought from your question that your app was ONLY crashing when run under lldb, and not when run normally.  But now it sounds like it also crashes when Double-Click launching more generally.   Is that right, and is the error the same?  If so, then there must actually be something wrong with the plist requesting camera access independent of the debugger.  That's not something I know much about.

Comment: Yeah, it crashes when not run under lldb. I want to run it under lldb to check it out. But then I run into the other problem of not being able to run because it wants to use the camera.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Does it crash before it gets to your main function (in library initialization or something like that) or does it crash after main?  If it crashes after main, then just put a `int foo = 1; while (foo) { sleep(1); }` into main, attach with lldb, do: `expr foo = 0` in lldb and continue.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I can do that because it does get a little ways before crashing. I just thought this would have been a solved problem on the Mac to debug programs that use protected services but maybe not.

Comment: were you able to find a workaround that does not involve attaching after using `open` or double clicking on the app package?

Comment: unfortunately no, @shaheen

Answer (score 4):

To allow your application to access the camera, you should have a `Info.plist` file with the field `NSCameraUsageDescription` filled with something.

If you're not building an application bundle (.app), then you can put the `Info.plist` next to your executable.
Then the next time you run it with `lldb` it will ask for authorization to access the camera.
Once you give it once, you might have to close the application and start it again.

According to my test, the following Info.plist content is enough :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Video Input</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Well, I already have a plist file with the requisite permissions for the Qt app and I'm pretty sure I've tried putting it in multiple places. But maybe I'll try a few more

Comment: afaik the `Info.plist` in the application bundle is only used when launching the app either by double clinking on it or with some osascript. If you run lldb, you might be passing the fullpath to the executable inside the .app as lldb argument. In that case I don't think that it will look in the upper folder for the plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Monterey (maybe also earlier versions) the app no longer crashes when the Info.plist is adjusted, but unfortunately it also does ***NOT*** show a camera image. Instead the view only shows a black screen.
It looks like macOS only allows access to the camera from applications that are located in the */Application* directory.
Workaround to debug the application:

1. move your application bundle generated by QtCreator into the /Application directory (the generated *.app file).
2. create a symbolic link from the /Application/*.app directory to the build directory (`ln -s /Application/MyFancyApp.app <MyFancyBuildDir>/`)

Now you can launch and debug the app as usual using the Qt Creator.

Comment: This method does not work on macOS Ventura (with Qt 5.12.12)